# Cache auto_increment values similar to sequences in Oracle

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

In Oracle it is possible to use a sequence to create id's for a DB key, and also to cache it:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE emp_sequence
      INCREMENT BY 1
      START WITH 1
      NOMAXVALUE
      NOCYCLE
      CACHE 10;
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar using MySQL and auto_increment?